# Weirdest issue with awesomium and javascript within c#

Tags: c#, awesomium

I am using Awesomium within C# and I am dragging variables out of the javascript within.

The code that is run:

```
           if (GotCategories == false) {
            if (WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("finished").ToString() == "true" && WebBrowser.IsDocumentReady == true) {
                int Level1Len = Convert.ToInt32(WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories.length").ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < Level1Len - 1; i++) {
                    string Level1 = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].title");
                    string Level1ID = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].id");
                    TreeNode treenode = new TreeNode(Level1);
                    CatsTree.Nodes.Add(treenode);
                    int Level2Len = Convert.ToInt32(WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub.length").ToString());
                    for (int j = 0; j < Level2Len; j++) {
                        string Level2 = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].title");
                        string Level2ID = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].id");
                        treenode = new TreeNode(Level2);
                        CatsTree.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(treenode);
                        int Level3Len = Convert.ToInt32(WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].sub.length").ToString());
                        for (int k = 0; k < Level3Len; k++) {
                            string Level3 = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].sub[" + k + "].title");
                            string Level3ID = WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].sub[" + k + "].id");
                            treenode = new TreeNode(Level3);
                            CatsTree.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes.Add(treenode);
                            if (WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].sub[" + k + "].sub.length").IsInteger == true) {
                                string Level4Len = Convert.ToInt32(WebBrowser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("all_categories[" + i + "].sub[" + j + "].sub[" + k + "].sub.length").ToString());
```

A weird issue happens though..

If I run it how it is now Level4Len throws an exception error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Though.. Weirdly enough if I put a `MessageBox.Show(Level4Len);` I do not receive the error and.. as well as that the outputs that are shown are completely normal as they should be.

Weirdest thing I have seen..

Comment: Depending on the time, 0 or 2

Comment: @GrantWinney my exact thought, ill give it a go and see how that works out, thanks! :)